# Is there any "Geometry Contour Line Algorithm"?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, contour

I want to find & draw contour lines like this.

[image]

Data is just List of (x,y,z) and only a few points (about 40~60) in there.
(x and y are position and z is height)

How can i find this contour line and point?

Comment: Do you need a vector representation of the contours? Or do you only care about getting the final image?

Comment: @samgak Only care about getting the final image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a first approximation, you can admit that your function is piecewise planar over a triangulation of the data points.

The Delaunay triangulation technique can be used, but in this case, given the regular polar arrangement, I guess that a simple rule based on the polar arguments could do.

Interpolating inside the triangles and obtaining the horizontal sections is a simple matter. Unfortunately, this will produce a gross approximation and you will probably notice artifacts due to the coarseness of the polylines.

A possible cure is to smooth the polylines as a postprocessing step, for instance turning them to polyBeziers.

Another method, which I prefer, is to use a higher order interpolation method. For C1 continuity, you can compute estimates of the gradient at the given points and fit quadratic functions on the triangles. Then subdivide the triangles in sub-triangles, interpolate the function at the sub-vertices, and switch to the planar model in these sub-triangles.

Answer (score 1):

As that looks like an irregular grid, you should first build a mesh around it (for instance, from a [Voronoi tesellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram)).

For every triangle, take the maximum and minimum heights of its vertices and find out the heights of the contour lines in that range (for instance, if you are drawing contour lines every 10 units and the heights of a triangle go from 11.5 to 34.2, the contour lines passing through that triangle are at heights 20 and 30).

Then approximating the height function inside the triangle as a linear function, find out where those contour lines lay and draw them.

Answer (score 0):

The data for the contour plot could be generated with a two-dimensional simplification of the marching cubes algorith, which is described [here](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/polygonise/). In the simplification, squares are used instead of cubes and four sampled values are used for the interpolation instead of the the eight corners of the cubes.

The simplification is also termed [marching squares](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_Squares).

Comment: The method must be adapted because the topology is not that of a square grid.